# Integer range assertion in junit?

Tags: junit

I'd like to write a junit assertion that expresses: "integer X must be between 10 and 17", but I can't find an easy way of doing this. Do I really need to implement a custom Matcher? I do want an error message that tells me what the actual value was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AssertJ](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/) has the `isBetween(a, b)` matcher built into its [AbstractIntegerAssert](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/core/api/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractIntegerAssert.html). A simple test case that reads like natural language will give a meaningful failure report "for free":

```java
Integer x = 5;
assertThat(x).isBetween(10, 17);
```

Output:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expecting:
 <5>
to be between:
 [10, 17]
```

Answer (score 4):

What is wrong with:

```
int high = 17;
int low = 10;
assertTrue(myInteger + " is not in [" + low + ", " + high + "]",
           myInteger >= low && myInteger <= high);
```

?

If you're using this more than once factor it out.

Comment: You could include myInteger into "My message", as OP requested. :)

Comment: @ReutSharabani: if you follow this line of thinking, all the API needs is `fail( msg )`, or perhaps `assertTrue( c, msg )`. All the other methods, like `assertEquals( one, two, msg )` are unnecessary. Given that they exist ... I guess I'm learning that the API is indeed uneven, and not just me not finding the call.